# Use openUDID with ARC system

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to use below library to do our device identification purposes:

https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

this library is working with non-arc mechanism and I am developing my app with ARC and I am not familiar with non-ARC features and mechanism. How should I convert this famous open source library so that can work with ARC too?

Comment: Have you asked Xcode to convert it?

Comment: Google: xcode convert to arc

Comment: I use edit->convert-> to objectivce-c arc but it can not convert it

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: I fixed it by instructions here: http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/10/24/migration-to-arc-automatic-reference-counting-using-xcode-4-2-refactor/
Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 4):

find OpenUDID in Build Phases, add "`-fno-objc-arc`"to OpenUDID.m compiler

[image]